# How to get bounding box from a postgis database in terms of degrees?

Tags: postgis, extents

How do you obtain the bounding box for a postgis database in terms of degrees (latitude in degrees and longitude in degrees)?

Comment: hmm.. are you wanting a bounding box for the entire _DATABASE_? Or a more granular asset in your database, like a table, collection of geometries, or just a singular geometry? Geometries and collections of geometries aren't so difficult (@alpha-beta-soup gave you the recipe), but getting the envelope of a complete table or of the database as a whole will require a little ingenuity.

Comment: I was looking for the entire database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ST_Extent(ST_Transform(the_geom,4326)) AS extent FROM sometable;
```

[ST_Extent](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) is an aggregate function.

[ST_Transform](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) takes an integer SRID as a second argument, so in this case it returns your geometry as WGS84 coordinates.

Comment: I would reverse the order of the `ST_Transform` and `ST_Extent` calls. Transform each coordinate and then get the extent of the reprojected points. The extreme points in each direction are not necessarily the same for the source and target CRS.

Comment: Good point @MatthiasKuhn, I have edited the answer to transform before getting the extent.